enable admin approval and email verification in ultimate member plugin
i use Ultimate Member for member registration , currently i have enabled admin approval for members .
I want to send email verification after admin approved a member, after email verification only the member should be able to login.
I want to add a domain whitelist and blacklist , eg if a user register with email from xyz .com it should get automatically approved and email verification should be sent to the email.

You'll have to ask the plugin's support team about this. Third-party plugin support is off topic here.
